# TeamCity + MSTest - Run only failed tests?

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, mstest, teamcity

Is there a way to run only failed tests from a previous test run in TeamCity?

Even better, is there a way to run only selected tests in some way?  Like if we want to run only certain test classes.

Is there another mechanism we can accomplish this with?  Maybe passing some kind of configuration file to MSTest on subsequent test run?

The reason I ask this, is we have employees that do not use Visual Studio, but they still need to run certain tests to see what is failing.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but this might not be a great idea.  Sometimes fixing one test can cause another previously passing test to break.

Comment: This is something that would be used only on occasion.  The full set of tests will still run every night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group those tests in a category. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx

Use the "Additional commandline parameters" in the MsTest Build Step to run only the test from your category.

Comment: I'll try this out, I believe it will work.  I'll mark you as the answer if successful.

Comment: It works great.  We are using NUnit now, but still works fine.