# Team city failed scenario

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, teamcity, perforce

I have given run my test cases on team city .Total test cases are 39 out of 11 are in failed status .I want to run only failed test cases.

Anyone who know how to run only failed test cases.

I am using C#,VS2015,Perfoce.[failed test cases screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSsYG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate [TeamCity + MSTest - Run only failed tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898853/teamcity-mstest-run-only-failed-tests)

Comment: Both are different

Comment: Could you specify what exactly is different in your case?

Comment: I have already added Additional command line parameters.I need to run only failed test cases.if you add parameter it will run only tagged test cases